# List returned by values_list queryset dont iterate

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have done something like this

```
def Categories(self):
    category_list = Category.objects.values_list("category", flat=True).filter(created_by=self.request.user)
    print(category_list)
    for categories in category_list:
        print(categories)
```

When I do this the first print statement prints the list of categories from my model but when I try to iterate it, it only gives the first value..
Like first print gives on the shell `[u'hi',u'ho',u'hell']`
But when I iterate the second print gives only 'hi'.
I don't know what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values_list` doesn't return `list`, but `ValuesListQuerySet`, which is kind of iterator and the first `print` probably... shift its pointer or something.

Convert it to `list`, it should work then.

```
category_list = list(Category.objects.values_list("category", flat=True).filter(created_by=self.request.user))
```

Comment: I tried converting it to list like u said but still the same problem.. I cant iterate over other values..

Comment: your question says `I have something like this`. It this exactly what you have? It might collide with some other variable you havent mentioned etc...

Comment: Like I said its showing the list but its just not iterating

Comment: Imho your problem is elsewhere, but there's not enough info to say where exactly. Try to separate each line if it behaves correctly, ie. print each element of the list if it gives expected result. try to use another variable to loop through if it behaves correctly etc.

Comment: what was the problem?